# How to send credentials with ngx-socket-io?

Tags: angular, socket.io, ngx-socket-io

I need to implement a socket.io client in Angular and I found ngx-socket-io. It seems to work fine, but I didn't find an option to send credentials when starting the connection, as described on the official page, using auth > token. (https://socket.io/docs/v4/middlewares/#Sending-credentials)

I already have the server implemented and working in this format, getting the data from `socket.handshake.auth.token`.

How do I send this token through ngx-socket-io?
Are there any other socket.io libraries that I can use in angular?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a workaround, inserting empty options in the constructor and adding authentication right after. It's not ideal, but it seems to work normally. I'm sharing it here in case anyone else needs it.

```
import { AuthService } from '@my/core';
import { Socket } from 'ngx-socket-io';
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';

export class MySocket extends Socket {
    constructor(
        private authService: AuthService,
    ) {
        super({ url: environment.urlSocket, options: {} });
        this.ioSocket['auth'] = { token: this.authService.token };
    }
}
```

Comment: What can we do if this.authService.token returns an observable. For example, if I am using a firebase authenticator

Comment: @MissakBoyajian use 
`this.socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3000', {
      path: '/chat',
      auth: async (cb: Function) => {
        const token = await authService.__auth.currentUser?.getIdToken();
        cb({ token: token });
      }
    });`

Comment: Seems with updated ngx-socket-io it is now under 
```this.socket['config'].options.auth.token = `Bearer ${authenticationResult.accessToken}`;```

Answer (score 1):

As the validated answer didn't fit my use case because my auth credentials get in an async manner I was looking for an other solution described below:

```
@Injectable()
export class LiveSocket extends Socket {
    constructor(private authService: AuthService) {

        super({
            url: environment.liveServiceUrl,
            options: {
                transports: ["websocket"],
                autoConnect: false
            }
        });

        this.authService.getCurrentUserObs()
            .pipe(filter(user => !!user))
            .subscribe(user => {
                this.ioSocket.session = {
                    token: user.token,
                    // other session data here
                };
                this.connect();
            });
    }
}


@NgModule({
    exports: [ SocketIoModule ],
    providers: [ LiveSocket ]
})
export class SocketModule {}
```

I set the `autoConnect: false` inside the config to prevent the connect at first to wait for my credentials to be accessed.

Then I subscribe to my service to get the auth data asynchronously.

Whenever I get a non-null `user` I set the handshake element with the data and then explicitly `connect()` the socket.

Be warned that a new connection will be established whenever a non-null `user` is fired from the `AuthService` and I didn't unsubscribe from the `Observable` so this can introduce some **memory leaks** depending on your implementations of the `Socket` and `AuthService`.

I'm not a pro of `ngx-socket-io` and don't know if this solution represents an anti-pattern or not, any suggestions are welcomed!

Answer (score 0):

You can create an Injectable service that you can use to initiate the Socket connection

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Socket } from 'ngx-socket-io';
import { AuthenticationService } from '@app/auth/services/authentication.service';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class WebSocketService {
  constructor(private socket: Socket, private authenticationService: AuthenticationService) {
    const currentUser = this.authenticationService.currentUserValue;
    this.socket.ioSocket.io.opts.query = { Authorization: `${currentUser.accessToken}` };
  }

  public sendMessage(event, message) {
    this.socket.emit(event, message);
  }

  public getMessage(eventName) {
    return new Observable(observer => {
      this.socket.on(eventName, message => {
        observer.next(message);
      });
    });
  }
}
```

In your component, you can inject your service:

```
import { WebSocketService } from './web-socket.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-conversation',
  templateUrl: './conversation.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./conversation.component.scss']
})
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor( private webSocket: WebSocketService) {}
  
  ngOnInit() {
    this.webSocket.getMessage('testing').subscribe(msg => console.log(msg));
   }
}
```

In your server, the token is received

```
handleConnection(socket: Socket) {
const token  = socket.handshake.query.Authorization;
```

Comment: Your suggestion doesn't solve my problem because it needs to use parameters sent by 'query', instead of using the Socket.io authentication standard. That way I would have to change the server, which I'm trying to avoid. I added an answer with the solution I found.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to add auth header this way:

```
var token = "...";
this.socket.ioSocket.io.opts.extraHeaders = {
    "Authorization": token
}
```